# php/mysql not counting rows in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this Query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as a from session ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$records = $stmt->fetch();
echo '- '.$result["a"];
```

but its just displaying:

-

on its own, with no number of records, i know there is rows because when i run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `session` as a
```

in PHPMyAdmin it shows all the rows there in the column a

why would this query not work?

Comment: nope you aliased the table, not the count. use `select count(*) a from session`

Comment: `echo '- '.$records["a"];`

Comment: Also, note that you assigned the result of `fetch()` to `$records`, but then you try to get the value of `$result["a"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt from `session` ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$records = $stmt->fetch();
echo '- '.$records["cnt"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go for a single column result you can use `fetchColumn()` and also you have aliased the table name not the column name

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*)  as a  from `session`");
$stmt->execute(array());
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

[PDOStatement::fetchColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

Answer (score 0):

why you are echoing `$result`.. you havent declared it..
use `$records`

`echo '- '.$records["a"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as a from `session` ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$records = $stmt->fetch();
echo '- '.$records["a"];
```