# php mysqli fetch result always returning 1

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

this is code i am trying to work with. i am checking number of total row in a table(how many people registered). my output don't have any error or so, i dont know what am i doing wrong. same thing was working yesterday. god knows what happened now

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM team"; 
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute(); 
$number= $result->fetch(); 
print_r($number);
var_dump($result);
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 

object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php  You haven't bound any variables, so there's nothing to fetch INTO. The fetch call itself only returns a true/false to indicate success/failure.

Comment: You have to bind your results before doing the fetch!

Comment: Have a look at [php/mysql not counting rows in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092953/php-mysql-not-counting-rows-in-table/22093033#22093033)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT count(1) FROM team";

if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($number);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

echo $number;
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM team";

if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $number = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

echo $number;
```